# How to customize ASP.NET Identity Core Username to allow special characters and space while registering

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I would like to use some special characters like ø, in the user name. I have set the 
`AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false`, but i'm getting an error like as below.

> **User name tew-wer is invalid, can only contain letters or digits.**

Can you please help me to solve this.

Comment: Please show the entire set of code that you're using to set this up (i.e. the rest of the code where you set `AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames`).

Comment: Implement your own `IPasswordValidator<TUser>` and register it instead of `PasswordValidator<TUser>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `startup.cs` configure identity services to include allowed chars in user name:

```
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(ops =>
{
    //--- other code

    ops.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = 
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
});
```